# Is it possible to start animation of text once it is in view only using CSS?

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-animations

I'm trying to animate a text when user scrolls it up in view only using CSS. 
Is it possible to do so?

Comment: The only way to listen a scroll event is with Javascript... You can animate text with only css but you need to listen the scroll event, so... javascript is necessary

Comment: Are you actually asking if it's possible or are you asking how to do it? See [this meta question as to why "is it possible" questions fare poorly here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270933/215552).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yes, I'm just asking if it is possible atall. Not asking for a "how to do it". Just so I get a closure on it.

Comment: Then it's really not much use to others... The answer is, as @MichaelCoker suggests, "no".

Comment: Well your discussion doesn't specify the detail of the answer you want.  It absolutely cannot be done using CSS alone.  It can be done using Javascript to change CSS attributes to perform the animation based on triggers on the page (scrolls into view).